# How to implode a string when have character?

Tags: php, regex, implode

For example, here is my string :

```
$text = "Iphone 4, Iphone 4S; Iphone 5, Iphone 3. Iphone 3S";
```

And splitting string:

```
$splitting_strings = array(".", ";", ".");
$result = array (
   0 => "Iphone 4",
   1 => "Iphone 4S",
   2 => "Iphone 5",
   3 => "Iphone 3",
   4 => "Iphone 3S"
);
```

I am using this code:

```
$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $splitting_strings) . ')/';
print_r(implode($regex, $text));
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to achieve? You cannot use different characters as delimiter when joining string, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: When you say `when meet character special` do you mean special characters for RegEx? Please give examples.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: I think @Hai Trunong wants the output mentioned by $text on imploding the array mentioned by $result using glues comma,semicolon and dot.Still Not sure what is required

Answer (score 2):

You can using `preg_split`

```
$text = "Iphone 4, Iphone 4S; Iphone 5, Iphone 3. Iphone 3S"; 
$array = preg_split("/[\s]*[,][\s]*/", $text);
print_r($array);
// Array ( [0] => Iphone 4 [1] => Iphone 4S [2] => Iphone 5 [3] => Iphone 3 [4] => Iphone 3S )
```

EDIT:

```
$array = preg_split("/[\s]*[,]|[;]|[.][\s]*/", $text);
```

Comment: your code will split the string based on comma only . The result will be like : 
Array ( [0] => Iphone 4 [1] => Iphone 4S; Iphone 5 [2] => Iphone 3 . Iphone 3S )

Comment: @HaiTruong : If splitting is your aim ,then what this mean "How to implode a string " ??? .Please give proper title.Dont confuse every one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = "Iphone 4, Iphone 4S; Iphone 5, Iphone 3. Iphone 3S";

$splitting_strings = array_map( 'preg_quote', array('.', ';', '.', ',' ) );

$result = array_map( 'trim', preg_split( '~' . implode( '|', $splitting_strings ) . '~', $text ) );
```

The value of `$result` is now the same as yours. Mind that I've used both preg_quote (to escape the characters) as trim.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative to using regexp (though a regexp solution is more efficient).

```
$text = "Iphone 4, Iphone 4S; Iphone 5, Iphone 3. Iphone 3S";
$separators = ',;.';

$word = strtok($text, $separators);
$arr = array();
do {
    $arr[] = $word;
    $word = strtok($separators);
} while (FALSE !== $word);

var_dump($arr);
```